# OpenShift Enterprise creating directories in root file system

Tags: openshift

We have several applications that look in a standard location for configuration on the file system. Something like:
/config/db/

There would simply be too many changes required to many applications to use $OPEN_SHIFT_DATA_DIR instead. Is there a way to put files in arbitrary directories? Do i have to create a custom cartridge that would put the config directory there? Are there any permissions restrictions that I'll run into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much experience with OSE, but only OSO.  My guess would be that you should package up your configurations as an RPM and install it as root on the system, with permissions that are permissive enough for the gears users to be able to access them.  Then release a new RPM for configuration changes.  Installing a cartridge to a gear should never allow the data to be accessed by another gear, or be able to install something to anywhere that is not in that users selinux container.

Comment: RPM packaging and deployment looks to be what makes the most sense, having a different gears deploy the same config directory into their data dir doesn't make much sense.